# SQL Update query on query result

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, inner-join

I have 2 tables like:

Table 1

```
SID     Sdefinition   CValue
4057    s1             32
4058    s2             
4059    s3             6
4060    s4
```

Mapping_tbl

```
SID     SINID   ECFID   SID-SINID
4057    1099    4027e   1099_4057
4058    1099    4027e   1099_4058
4059    1121    4003e   1121_4059
4060    1121    4003e   1121_4060
```

Query1

```
  SELECT Mapping_tbl.SID, Table1.Sdefinition, Table1.CValue
  FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Mapping_tbl ON Table1.SID= Mapping_tbl.SID;
```

Query1(Result)

```
   SID  Sdefinition CValue
   4057    s1      32
   4058    s2      
   4059    s3      6
   4060    s4
```

I have a situation that I wanted to update query table (Query1) i.e
 set field(Cvalue) to 0 if it contains null. I am using update query like

```
   Update Query1 Set CValue = 0 Where CValue Is Null;
```

The query table (query1) gets updated and sets Cvalue to 0 if it
 contains nulls, and it also updates(set 0) Table1 where Cvalues are
 null.

How can I avoid updating Table1? Any suggestions.

Comment: Table one is the underlying table, it's going to update. Are you just trying to display 0 instead of null in the query output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPDATE from SELECT using SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Comment: @Carl Sixsmith Yes, just trying to display 0 instead of null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't want to change the values stored in your table, and you want the query to display zero when *CValue* is Null.  So you can have the query substitute zero for Null in its result set only (without changing values in the table) ...

```sql
SELECT m.SID, t.Sdefinition, IIf(t.CValue Is Null, 0, t.CValue) AS [CValue]
FROM Table1 AS t INNER JOIN Mapping_tbl AS m
ON t.SID= m.SID;
```

For a query in an Access session, you could use the VBA `Nz()` function ...

```sql
SELECT m.SID, t.Sdefinition, Nz(t.CValue Is Null, 0) AS [CValue]
FROM Table1 AS t INNER JOIN Mapping_tbl AS m
ON t.SID= m.SID;
```

I used aliases for the table names.  But you don't need them for Null substitution to work.   I just prefer aliases.

Comment: Didnt realise it was access, this is a better answer than mine

Comment: Yes, Access `IsNull` is different than SQL Server's.  In Access, it accepts only one argument and returns a boolean ... but it doesn't substitute anything for the Null value.

Comment: Worked like charm, you are brilliant HansUp